# How can I pass a parameter to a role in Ansible from inventory file?

Tags: ansible

I have a set of roles that are all unique and use a common role that is pulled in via a dependency to perform a bunch of the same actions that all these other roles need to have done.   I need to be able to pass into a specific role a parameter to say in this case pull a docker image from a registry, in that other case save the image out and do some other things.  Variables cause issues as they are explicit for a host and I might have several roles per host.  How can I structure my ansible playbook to do this?

Example:
I have a common role that is pulled into other roles as a dependency:

```
---

- name: Included Playbook - What vars do I see
  debug:
        msg: "Name Pull: {{ imagename }}"

- name: Local Running
  debug:
        msg: "Local option selected"
  when: localimage == "true"

- name: Not local
  debug:
        msg: "Not Local remote"
  when: localimage == "false"
```

Then the primary role tasks\main.yml

```
---

- name: Included Playbook - What vars do I see from Primary
  vars:
        myname: "{{ imagemainname }}"
  debug:
        msg: "Name-primary: {{ myname }}"
```

and its meta\main.yml

```
---

dependencies:
   - { role: image-pull, imagename: "{{ imagemainname }}" }
```

This is the same for a second role
    ---

```
- name: Included Playbook - What vars do I see from Second
  vars:
        myname: "{{ secondname }}"
  debug:
        msg: "Name-second: {{ myname }}"
```

and its meta\main.yml

```
---

dependencies:
   - { role: image-pull, imagename: "{{ secondname }}" }
```

My main playbook calls both primary and second roles and the role specific vars works fine.

```
---

- name: Master
  hosts: imagemaster
  remote_user: root
  vars:
         imagemainname: "Top Dog"
  roles:
        - image-master

- name: Second
  hosts: second
  remote_user: root
  vars:
         imagemainname: "Second Dog"
  roles:
        - second
```

What doesn't work is when I want to state the do option a or b in the "pulled" role.

If my inventory file looks like this:

```
[imagemaster]
127.0.0.1

[imagemaster:vars]
localimage=false

[second]
127.0.0.1

[second:vars]
localimage=true
```

It doesn't work as whatever is the last entry for localimage is what all roles will use.

What can I do to pass in something from the inventory/host_vars/etc that means my playbook doesn't change for every iteration in this setup?

Comment: Are you aware of this statement: ["expected behavior is that the var will have the value of the last group loaded"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6538#issuecomment-37885348)? You need to rethink your playbook, or wait for some cynophilist who would grasp your objectives.

Comment: That's why I'm asking.  How do I restructure the playbook to accomplish something like this or is it even possible to pass in some kind of parameter to a playbook that is held to the role?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to apply primary and secondary role to the same host (as in your example (127.0.0.1), then you have no options:

> Within any section, redefining a var will overwrite the previous instance. If multiple groups have the same variable, the last one loaded wins. If you define a variable twice in a play’s vars: section, the 2nd one wins.

(from the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html))

If you plan to apply them to different hosts, then test is properly, e.g.:

```
[imagemaster]
127.0.0.1

[imagemaster:vars]
localimage=false

[second]
127.0.1.1

[second:vars]
localimage=true
```

In this scenario, when role (primary/secondary) is applied to `imagemaster` group, then `localimage=false`; when applied to `second` group – `localimage=true`.